# __bases__ not working on Python 3.5?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i've implemented a small code following a book for py33 in py35. I am trying to get the super classes instances from a given subclass as follows:

```
class Super:
    def hello(self):
        self.data1 = 'spam'

class Sub(Super):
    def hola(self):
        self.data2 = 'eggs'

X = Sub()
X.__dict__
X.__class__
X.__bases__
```

However, when i excecute the `X.__bases__` command i get an error:

```
AttributeError: 'Sub' object has no attribute '__bases__'
```

Could someone explain to me why is this happening and how can I (if not so) get the instances of the superclasses of a given class?

Thanks to you all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it from the class, not the instance, see the [documentation of `__bases__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#class.__bases__):

> `class.__bases__`
>
> The tuple of base classes of a class object.

so, in short, use `type(X).__bases__`.